# Bash syntax variable value assignment

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting. I came across the following piece of code and I am not able to figure it out. Please help me understand.

```
var1=$var1 some_function_call $var2
```

var2 is argument to "some_function_call" function.

I am not able to figure out exactly what is going on here. Thanks in advance.

Also any pointer to good bash scripting tutorials would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment of the new `some_function_call` process has "var1" set to the value of `$var1`; the environment variable does not change in the main interpreter. The value in `$var2` is passed as an argument to `some_function_call`.

Comment: there is no 'env' in the code, is 'env' implicit? Meaning is the above code snippet same as `env var1=$var1 some_function_call $var2` . 
From what I understand by your reply, when `some_function` runs it has the value of 'var1' as set in this piece of code and the value of 'var1' changes only in execution scope of `some_function` (if var1 was '1' before this function call and var1 is assigned value '2' in this code then var1 is 2 in `some_function` and 1 otherwise? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @CodeWithPride: Yes, except that none of the arguments of `env` are supported, and there is no intermediate process between the interpreter and `some_function_call`.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of the arguments of `env` are supported".
Also, I am unaware of the concept of "intermediate process" in bash. 
Kindly help in explanation or any links/references where I can understand these things would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `env` has arguments it takes that changes its behavior; -i, -0, etc. If you use `env` then bash runs `env` and then `env` runs your program, hence `env` is an intermediate process.